# Preprocessing weird data in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, data-science, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I am working with a set of climate data that come in a very strange distribution and is difficult to work with. I decided to work with pyspark because it is a large volume of data, you know, with the idea of saving time.

The data format is .ascii/.text/.dat, whatever you want to call it, And the distribution is as follows:

---

| Date 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 | Value 10 | Value 11 | Value 12 |
| . | . | . | . | . | Value 101178 |
| **Date 2** |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 | Value 10 | Value 11 | Value 12 |
| . | . | . | . | . | Value 101178 |

---

That is, it is a table composed of tables of 101178 data distributed in 6 columns (16863 rows).

In case the explanation is not very clear, I attach a link to a small fragment of the file. (the original file is >50GB)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-aJRTWzpQ5lHyZgt-h7DuEY5GpYZRcUh/view?usp=sharing

My idea is to generate a matrix with the following structure:

---

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Date n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value1.2 | Value1.n |
| Value 2 | Value2.2 | Value2.n |
| Value n | Valuen.2 | Valuen.n |

---

I have tried to make the question as clear as possible. As I said I am working with pyspark so if anyone has any solution to do this data processing using this tool I would be very grateful.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: What is the header row in the data meant to be?

Comment: Date in 10 digit format (1991010100 = 1991/01/01 00h), the first 0 don't know what it means, the second one is the layer of the data (usually use to identify different depth in some variables) and the 101178 is the number of points that you are studying. The only relevant information for me is the date.

Comment: Cool, well I have added and answer. I captured all of those fields in the regex. I'm sure you can figure it out from there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it very close, but not exactly, to your expected dataframe structure.

To test code's output I made this dummy dataset to play with, because it's super hard to follow lots of number in your original dataset

```sh
+--------------------------------------------+
|value                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  1990010100           0           0      24|
|  001  002  003  004  005  006              |
|  007  008  009  010  011  012              |
|  013  014  015  016  017  018              |
|  019  020  021  022  023  024              |
|  1990010101           0           0      24|
|  101  102  103  104  105  106              |
|  107  108  109  110  111  112              |
|  113  114  115  116  117  118              |
|  119  120  121  122  123  124              |
|  1990010102           0           0      24|
|  201  202  203  204  205  206              |
|  207  208  209  210  211  212              |
|  213  214  215  216  217  218              |
|  219  220  221  222  223  224              |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

And here is the complete code that I tested out. The main idea is to mark the date block and its records somehow so they can join with each other.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

# I'm not sure what cluster do you have, or you're going to run on your local machine, so I added this piece here for your reference. The most important thing is you would want to provide enough resources to handle entire dataset all at once.
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .master('local[*]')
    .appName('SO')
    .config('spark.driver.cores', '4')
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '4g')
    .config('spark.executor.cores', '4')
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '4g')
    .getOrCreate()
)

# load raw weird data and apply some transformation to make it "readable" or "processable"
df = (spark
    .read.text('t2.dat')
    .withColumn('id', F.row_number().over(W.orderBy(F.lit(1)))) # making ID per row, very important to mark the dates
    .withColumn('value', F.trim(F.col('value')))         # trim spaces before and after
    .withColumn('value', F.split(F.col('value'), '\s+')) # turn single line to individual values
)
# +------------------------------+---+
# |value                         |id |
# +------------------------------+---+
# |[1990010100, 0, 0, 24]        |1  |
# |[001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006]|2  |
# |[007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012]|3  |
# |[013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018]|4  |
# |[019, 020, 021, 022, 023, 024]|5  |
# |[1990010101, 0, 0, 24]        |6  |
# |[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]|7  |
# |[107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]|8  |
# |[113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118]|9  |
# |[119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124]|10 |
# |[1990010102, 0, 0, 24]        |11 |
# |[201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206]|12 |
# |[207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212]|13 |
# |[213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218]|14 |
# |[219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224]|15 |
# +------------------------------+---+

# Extracting available date blocks
date_df = (df
    .where(F.size('value') == 4)
    .withColumn('grp', ((F.col('id') - 1) / 5).cast('int')) # replace 5 with 16864 when run with your actual dataset
    .select('grp', F.col('value')[0].alias('date'))
)
date_df.show(10, False)
# +---+----------+
# |grp|date      |
# +---+----------+
# |0  |1990010100|
# |0  |1990010101|
# |0  |1990010102|
# +---+----------+

# Extracting available value blocks
value_df = (df
    .where(F.size('value') == 6)
    .withColumn('grp', ((F.col('id') - 1) / 5).cast('int')) # replace 5 with 16864 when run with your actual dataset
    .groupBy('grp')
    .agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('value'))
    .withColumn('value', F.flatten('value'))
)
# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |grp|value                                                                                                                   |
# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |0  |[001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 020, 021, 022, 023, 024]|
# |1  |[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124]|
# |2  |[201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224]|
# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# join them together and "explode" array to different rows
joined_df = (date_df
    .join(value_df, on=['grp'])
    .withColumn('value', F.explode('value'))
)
# +---+----------+-----+
# |grp|date      |value|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |0  |1990010100|001  |
# |0  |1990010100|002  |
# |0  |...       |...  |
# |0  |1990010100|023  |
# |0  |1990010100|024  |
# |1  |1990010101|101  |
# |1  |1990010101|102  |
# |1  |...       |...  |
# |1  |1990010101|123  |
# |1  |1990010101|124  |
# |2  |1990010102|201  |
# |2  |1990010102|202  |
# |2  |...       |...  |
# |2  |1990010102|223  |
# |2  |1990010102|224  |
# +---+----------+-----+

# now, joined_df is basically holding your entire dataset, it's totally up to you how do you want to handle it.
# One option is you can save each date as a partition of one Hive table.
# Another option is saving each date as a file.
# It's just for the sake of simplicity when you'll ever need to read that painful dataset again.
for date in [row['date'] for row in date_df.collect()]:
    (joined_df
        .where(F.col('date') == date)
        .write
        .mode('overwrite')
        .csv(date)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

After your comment I have revised my answer, not that I have used 'pandas' and their dataframe, this should directly translate to spark if necessary.

Also I think your data is corrupt as the last array is not the correct length **MY CODE DOES NOT HANDLE THIS** so you will need to using the captured value from the regex `expected_values = m.group(4)` etc.

WARNING: The `:=` operator requires Python 3.8... but you can fix that up if you need to

NOTES:

- The header of each 'section' is captured by the regex and is used to form the column name

Split the file on the date row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from pathlib import Path

header = re.compile(r"^\s+(\d{10})\s+(\d*)\s+(\d*)\s+(\d*)$")

df = pd.DataFrame()

with open("t2.dat", "r") as ifp:
    rows = []
    date = None
    count = 0
    
    while line := ifp.readline():
        # Get the header and start a new file
        if m := header.match(line):
            # We have a header so convert to array then flatten to a vector
            # before appending to the dataframe.
            if rows and date:
                df[date] = np.array(rows, dtype=float).flatten(order="C")
                rows = []
                
            # Get the header
            date = m.group(1)
            
        else:
            rows.append(line.strip().split())
    
    print(f"Appending the last {len(rows)*len(rows[0])} values")
    df[date] = np.array(rows, dtype=float).flatten(order="C")
```

Output an abbreviated form (there is 1 column per date with 101178 rows:

```
    1990010100  1990010101  1990010102  1990010103  1990010104
0   10.4310 10.0490 9.7269  9.3801  9.0038
1   10.3110 9.9225  9.5431  9.1758  8.7899
2   10.2290 9.8144  9.4156  9.0304  8.6171
3   10.1500 9.7154  9.2999  8.8890  8.4713
4   9.8586  9.3968  8.9156  8.4328  7.9764
... ... ... ... ... ...
101173  -1.5511 -1.5472 -1.5433 -1.5251 -1.5399
101174  -1.8659 -1.8719 -1.8485 -1.8481 -1.8325
101175  -1.9044 -1.8597 -1.7963 -1.8094 -1.7653
101176  -2.0564 -2.0404 -1.9779 -1.9893 -1.9521
101177  -2.1842 -2.2840 -2.3216 -2.2794 -2.2655
```

Comment: Hi, Kevin, thank you for your solution. So what your code does its to separate the original data in files base on the date, what I need to do now is to select the first element of each one generate a column (and then with the second, third, and so one). Should I iterate  over the generated files to do this? Is there any form to change your code to directly select the values and store them into different columns/arrays? 
To make you clear what this means, each of the data for each array correspond to one spatial point so I should group them to evaluate how a point change over time.

Comment: I've revised it now @shevelp it is now closer to what you asked for in your question, 1 column per date. I mentioned it in my answer, but I'll say it here as well - there is something wrong with your last matrix of values there isn't enough. Maybe it is just because of how you split it?

Comment: Yes, the matrix is incomplete because of the split I've made. The solution is perfect now! Thank you very much for your time! @Kevin Glasson

Comment: Sorry for refloating the question again @Kevin Glasson, I've been trying to translate your code to use pyspark for a few days and there's no way. Running it locally using pandas with the full database gives error. Can you think of a way to implement the response in pyspark?